# Indentation error and undefined variables

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, undefined, indentation

Can someone tell me what's the flaw here? I get: `IndentationError: unexpected indent`. Is it really an indentation error? I don't understand why there are "undefined" variables even though they sure are defined above in the code.

[image]

The entire cell is here:

```
def portfolio_annualised_performance(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix):
    returns = np.sum(mean_returns*weights ) *252
    std = np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T, np.dot(cov_matrix, weights))) * np.sqrt(252)
    return std, returns
def random_portfolios(num_portfolios, mean_returns, cov_matrix, risk_free_rate):
    results = np.zeros((3,num_portfolios))
    weights_record = []
    for i in range(num_portfolios):
        weights = np.random.random(len(stocks) )
        weights /= np.sum(weights)
        weights_record.append(weights)
        portfolio_std_dev, portfolio_return = portfolio_annualised_performance(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix)
        results[0,i] = portfolio_std_dev
        results[1,i] = portfolio_return
        results[2,i] = (portfolio_return - risk_free_rate) / portfolio_std_dev
    return results, weights_record
def neg_sharpe_ratio(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix, risk_free_rate):
    p_var, p_ret = portfolio_annualised_performance(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix)
    return -(p_ret - risk_free_rate) / p_var
def max_sharpe_ratio(mean_returns, cov_matrix, risk_free_rate):
    num_assets = len(mean_returns)
    args = (mean_returns, cov_matrix, risk_free_rate)
    constraints = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x) - 1})
    bound = (0.0,1.0)
    bounds = tuple(bound for asset in range(num_assets))
    result = sco.minimize(neg_sharpe_ratio, num_assets*[1./num_assets,], args=args,
                        method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds, constraints=constraints)
    return result
def portfolio_volatility(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix):
    return portfolio_annualised_performance(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix)[0]
def min_variance(mean_returns, cov_matrix):
    num_assets = len(mean_returns)
    args = (mean_returns, cov_matrix)
    constraints = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x) - 1})
    bound = (0.0,1.0)
    bounds = tuple(bound for asset in range(num_assets))
result = sco.minimize(portfolio_volatility, num_assets*[1./num_assets,], args=args,
                        method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds, constraints=constraints)
    return result
```

Comment: The line with `result` is incorrectly indented, as the error suggests. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 2):

Your code (with a comment from me)

```
def min_variance(mean_returns, cov_matrix):
    num_assets = len(mean_returns)
    args = (mean_returns, cov_matrix)
    constraints = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x) - 1})
    bound = (0.0,1.0)
    bounds = tuple(bound for asset in range(num_assets))

# this is un-indented, which to Python means
# it's a line of code outside the min_variance method
result = sco.minimize(portfolio_volatility, num_assets*[1./num_assets,], args=args,
                        method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds, constraints=constraints)
    return result
```

Your `result =` line is un-indented, so it's not part of the `min_variance` method.

If you indent it, it should look like this and resolve your immediate issue.

```
def min_variance(mean_returns, cov_matrix):
    num_assets = len(mean_returns)
    args = (mean_returns, cov_matrix)
    constraints = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x) - 1})
    bound = (0.0,1.0)
    bounds = tuple(bound for asset in range(num_assets))

    result = sco.minimize(portfolio_volatility, num_assets*[1./num_assets,], args=args,
                        method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds, constraints=constraints)
    return result
```

Comment: Oh my it was that simple :D Thank you very much!